# How to include a CSS link if a call isn't done via AJAX?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I have a page '`foo.html`' that populates a table via AJAX `'ajax.html?options=option1'`(accesses a database.)

'`foo.html`' has a css linked to it that makes the table from ajax.html look nice. However, I'd like to have ajax.html also look nice with a css if it is directly accessed. if I add `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dev/css/default.css" />` then the AJAX inserts the link again in foo.html which I don't want. Is there any way I can make the css link code not show up in the AJAX call or only show up on non-AJAX calls?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a particular JS library to achieve the Ajax?

Comment: Your ajax call is returning html?

Comment: Your method is probably flawed. It sounds you're trying to load a complete webpage into another webpage, which is bad practice. It's better to have two versions of the table page: one page that is viewable as a separate page with head, body, css, and one version with only the <table>.

Comment: @David: I'm using cakePHP, so it would be scriptaculous and prototype

Comment: @Blaise I've done exactly what you mentioned, however I want the page with just the table to be viewable with the css if it's loaded directly

Comment: @madeinstefano: yes -a table. As far as I know <table><tr>... is HTML. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an easy way i can think of to solve this problem is to pass an additional parameter that defines the calling context.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use jQuery.

Load the ajax.html page with jQuery.get()
on success, do : 
Remove the stylesheet : `$('link[rel=stylesheet]').remove()`;

If you then want to add another stylesheet :

```
var link = $("<link>");
link.attr({
        type: 'text/css',
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'http://domain.com/stylesheet.css'
});
$("head").append( link );
```

Or change it later :

```
$("link").attr("href","http://domain.com/stylesheet.css");
```